# Why is this Go/GraphQL query returning HTTP 415 error?

Tags: go, graphql

I am trying to follow the Go/ GraphQL recipe of [1](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2020/02/interacting-with-a-graphql-api-with-golang/) to connect to a specific API. The following works in Python/ Jupyter:

```
import requests
import json

query = """query lineSearch {
  lines(transportModes: water) {
    id
    quays {
      name
      id
      latitude
      longitude
    }
    transportSubmode
  }
}"""

url = 'https://api.entur.io/journey-planner/v2/graphql'
r = requests.post(url, json={'query': query})
print(r.text)
```

The following Go attempt returns `HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type` in Goland IDE.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    jsonData := map[string]string{
        "query": `query {lines(transportModes: water) {id quays {name id latitude longitude} transportSubmode }}`,
    }
    jsonValue, _ := json.Marshal(jsonData)
    request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api.entur.io/journey-planner/v2/graphql",
        bytes.NewBuffer(jsonValue))
    client := &http.Client{Timeout: time.Second * 10}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    defer response.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("The HTTP request failed with error %s\n", err)
    }
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Am I making any obvious Python-to-Go translation mistakes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably missing the header `Content-Type: application/json`.

Just add

```
request.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

below request creation